# Postgres create Rule with error cannot convert relation containing dropped columns to view

Tags: postgresql

I am working on an API that deletes a row, instead of doing delete statement,
I created a column called "is_deleted" as boolean (default false and to be updated as true when the delete API triggered), then I am trying to make a DB RULE to select only when "is_deleted" = false

PG SQL CODE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE "_RETURN" 
AS
ON SELECT TO 
    public.TABLE_NAME
DO INSTEAD 
    SELECT Col1 , Col2 , Col3
    FROM public.TABLE_NAME
        WHERE is_deleted = false;
```

But when I run the RULE I end up with the following Error

```
ERROR:  cannot convert relation containing dropped columns to view
SQL state: 0A000
```

NOTE THAT Col1 , Col2 , Col3 are all in the TABLE And were not deleted

You support with the Query is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By creating this rule you turn the table into a view that references itself, which won't work. Don't directly create rules unless you are a PostgreSQL expert, they don't work as you think they would.

Create a view and use that in your queries:

```
CREATE VIEW public.table_view AS
SELECT Col1 , Col2 , Col3
FROM public.TABLE_NAME
WHERE is_deleted = false;
```